# Why should an Antivirus component use 27GB of data

Tags: windows, anti-virus

For the first time, I checked my data usage (past 30 days) on my Windows laptop and I was surprised to see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opnPf.png)

I'm using an antivirus called K7 Total Security, and I'm aware that it updates very frequently but 27 GB a month seems like overkill to me. Is it normal for an antivirus to consume so much data?

EDIT: I posted a question on their forum and they [replied](https://support.k7computing.com/index.php?/forums/topic-details/does-k7-total-security-use-upto-27gb-a-month).

Comment: Online analysis perhaps _(e.g. uploading files to check signatures)_? The best answer is going to come directly from the developer [K7 Total Security] - have you reached out to them?

Comment: Also make sure there is only one K2TWP.exe on your system.

Comment: Also ask the Software support people about this.

Comment: Saw a similar question on their forum which was posted 3 yrs back but a quantitative solution hasn't been posted yet. I've added a post on their wall.

Comment: Please post summary of support response as an answer so others will easier find it in the future.